# mysql query to join 4 tables based on multiple criteria

Tags: mysql, join

I have four tables in mysql as below:

[image]

[image]

What I want to do is join the tables together to show if the training has been done for each user in a department, if it has been done show the date of training else say training needed.

so desired output for department finance would be something like:

[image]

I have tried with the below code but the joins become inaccurate and invalid.

```
select o.person, o.job, j.risk, r. training,c.course,
    c.person,c.datecompleted 
from orgstructure o 
left outer join jobsrisks j 
    on o.job=j.job 
left outer join risktraining r 
    on j.risk=r.risk 
left outer join coursescompleted c 
    on o.person=c.person 
where o.department='finance'
```

should I be embedding multiple select queries into one? any help is appreciated.

Comment: How your query becomes `inaccurate and invalid`? Please explain.

Comment: Hi Mahmoud, appreciate your time. bluefeet nailed it below, the second on condition was not in place so the relationship for the join not accurate.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am going to guess that that issue is that you are joining the `orgstructure` to `coursescompleted` by `person` only, I think you also need to join on training:

```
select o.person, 
  o.job, 
  j.risk, 
  r.training,
  c.course,
  c.person,
  c.datecompleted 
from orgstructure o 
left outer join jobsrisks j 
  on o.job=j.job 
left outer join risktraining r 
  on j.risk=r.risk 
left outer join coursescompleted c 
  on o.person=c.person 
  and r.training = c.course   --- add this
where o.department='finance'
```

You need to join on the person plus if that person has a completed the course for each risk associated with the job.

Putting the entire query together you will have:

```
select o.person, 
  o.job, 
  j.risk, 
  r.training,
  case when c.course is null then 'no' else 'yes' end TrainingCompleted,
  coalesce(c.datecompleted, 'n/a') datecompleted
from orgstructure o 
left outer join jobsrisks j 
  on o.job=j.job 
left outer join risktraining r 
  on j.risk=r.risk 
left outer join coursescompleted c 
  on o.person=c.person 
  and r.training = c.course   
where o.department='finance'
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1110/7)

The result is:

```
|        PERSON |        JOB |                     RISK |                  TRAINING | TRAININGCOMPLETED |       DATECOMPLETED |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| taylor chetty |    manager |                   safety |          induction course |                no |                 n/a |
| taylor chetty |    manager |                 security |           security course |                no |                 n/a |
| bill thompson | data clerk |              bad posture | personal wellbeing course |                no |                 n/a |
| bill thompson | data clerk | repetitive strain injury |            nursing course |               yes | 2000-04-13 00:00:00 |
| bill thompson | data clerk |                   safety |          induction course |               yes | 2007-12-04 00:00:00 |
|     ann brown | data clerk |              bad posture | personal wellbeing course |                no |                 n/a |
|     ann brown | data clerk | repetitive strain injury |            nursing course |                no |                 n/a |
|     ann brown | data clerk |                   safety |          induction course |                no |                 n/a |
```

Comment: Legend, thank you. never realized you could have multiple 'on' conditions for a single join. thank you!

Comment: Hi, what does coalesce(c.datecompleted, 'n/a') datecompleted do? I understand the output but never seen `coalesce`? Thanks again,